# Python os cmd is not working inside nested IF of IFELSE functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

The first thing is I'm trying this in my Windows 10 machine. (Using Python 3.8.2)

```
import os

with open("ip.txt","r") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()

for ip in (lines):
    ip=ip[:-1]
    if ip != 0:
        print (ip)
        g = input("Wanna proceed (y or n) : ")

        if g == 'y':
           os.system('cls')    // This sould clear the screen in windows termimal.
```

ERROR:

```
 File ".\abuseipdb.py", line 19
    os.system('cls')
                   ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: is your indention 4 spaces or 2 spaces?

Comment: When you see an error like that, trust that it is telling you the truth.

Comment: The shown code sample has the wrong comment syntax `//`. Just copy & paste the original code. If you want to add comments or other things do it beforehand and run the code to check for (other) errors.

Comment: After removing the comment the code as posted does not have an indentation error. Considering where the error is marked, it looks like you've hit one of python's oddities. Its an unindent error on the _next_ line that is not shown here.

Answer (score -1):

The double backslashes are not comments in Python, so this may be the problem.

Also, you need to figure out if all that whitespace is a space or a tab.

Comment: actually i did that for just for info

Comment: Are my comments not helpful?  Generally post working code.  Changing from // to # is trivial.  Please read the comment by tdelaney.